# Решение задач как метод самооценки

Tags: тестирование

Решал задачу по циклам, нужно нарисовать ромб, заполненный символом "Х". В итоге решить самостоятельно не смог. Хочу спросить, насколько это страшно, если я не смог решить задачу такого плана и что мне посоветуете для исправления таких моментов?

Comment: Math.round(n/2)-1 пробелов; 1 крест
Math.round(n)-2 пробелов; 2 креста
...
1 пробелов; n-1 крестов
0 пробелов; n -крестов
1 пробелов; n-1 крестов
...
Math.round(n/2)-1 пробелов; 1 крест
Math.round(n)-2 пробелов; 2 креста

Вот решение, не поленитесь написать

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритмическое мышление развивать и воображение =)

Для конкретно этой задачи - нарисовать то же самое на листочке посимвольно и придумать, как это же самое выводить можно программно.

```
    X    
   XXX   
  XXXXX  
 XXXXXXX 
  XXXXX
   XXX
    X
```

Если же идеи есть, как подобные задачи решаются, то, значит, надо потренировать синтаксис и возможности языка. То есть почитать литературу по нему и порешать задачки. Чтобы понимать, как на программе записать свой придуманный алгоритм.

Comment: Не делать выводы того, что выйдет из меня плохой программист?

Comment: Используйте комментарии. Ну, учитесь и научитесь, что тут ещё сказать? =) То, что кто-то не может найти производную в 10 классе, не означает, что это у него никогда не получится. Был бы стимул...

Comment: Тот факт, что вы не решили эту задачу несомненно указывает на низкое развитие соответствующего склада ума. Это означат, что прямо сейчас не выйдет. Однако, как уже сказал предыдущий ответчик, это совершенно не значит, что вы не способны вообще. Для того чтобы добиться своего, вам надо много работать над собой. Если вам <= 18 лет, то ещё ничего не потеряно, а если > 20, то надо пахать и пахать, потому что уже много времени потеряно.

Comment: Решать побольше задач по программированию - способ решить даную проблему?

Comment: Ключевое - решать побольше задач =) Не обязательно по программированию. Может быть, на сообразительность, инженерные (как бы что-то сделать так, да чтоб и работало даже), ну и по программированию.

Comment: Путь, который помог мне много лет назад, когда я был ещё ребёнком: каждый раз как только я вижу что-то, я задумывался, как это сделано? Как бы я это сделал? Как бы я сделал это, если бы был ограничен, как машина? Важно не отсупать от попытки решения под каким-нибудь предлогом, а вырабатывать хоть какое-то решение. Такой нездоровый интерес закончился тем, что я, например, в итоге добился своего.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал бы структурировать сначала свои мысли и идеи по поводу задачи.

Вот, например, ромб.

Я вижу, что тут нужно 2 функции (лично мне):

1. Функция, которая принимает на вход строку, состоящую из X и дополняет ее до общей длины пробелами справа и слева, т.е. центрует.
2. Функция, которая принимает на вход ширину ромба и высоту. Она просто поделит высоту пополам, и пройдет циклом до середины высоты, прибавляя X, а после этого отбавляя X от строки, каждый раз передавая значение в первую функцию и полученный результат прибавляя к выходной переменной.

Вот так выглядит логика решения этой задачи у меня в голове на момент ее представления.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае успешность решения задач не является достаточным критерием для самооценки способностей, но является достаточным критерием для самооценки навыка. Программирование как форма умственного труда включает, как минимум:

1. разработку алгоритмов
2. написание текстов

Разработка алгоритмов требует математических способностей, написание текстов требует языковых способностей. В случае наличия оных (а по завершении средней школы уже очевидно, есть таковые способности или нет) рано или поздно навык решения задач по программированию придет, в случае отсутствия - не придет.

Comment: Способ один, решать побольше задач с программирования? Вы пишете, что рано или поздно навык придет, а в случае отсутствия - не придет. Не ясно в случае отсутствия чего?

Comment: Важны математические и языковые способности. Все остальное придет с практикой.

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший способ научиться - учить других. Походите по сайтам и найдите такой, где нерадивые школьники и студенты просят решить за них задания. Попытайтесь решить. Не думайте, что не сможете. Вы не представляете, какую тривиальщину там часто просят, на уровне "сложить два числа и вывести сумму на экран". Не можете сделать сами - подождите, пока кто-то другой ответит. Посмотрите на его решение, попытайтесь вникнуть в его логику.

Советую три книги: Жак Арсак - Программирование игр и головоломок; Керниган, Ритчи - Язык программирования C; Броуди - Начальный курс программирования на языке Форт.

Да, и чуть не забыл: А.А.Ивин - Искусство правильно мыслить. Эту книгу прочесть первой! К программированию она отношения не имеет, но мозги очень хорошо настраивает на нужный лад.

Программирование - это как езда на велосипеде. Не расстраивайтесь, что один раз упали. Вы ещё не раз упадёте. И я падаю. Но чем чаще падаешь, тем легче подниматься и ехать дальше.